# How to import ora in my customized mocha reporter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, commonjs

I want to add a customized ora (fancy spinners) reporter for mocha test framework in my Node.js project which uses ECMAScript Modules.

mocha-ora-reporter.cjs

```
const ora = require('ora')

module.exports = function oraReporter(runner) {
    const spinner = ora('Running tests...').start()

    runner.on('start', () => {
        spinner.start()
    })

    runner.on('pass', () => {
        spinner.succeed('Tests passed!')
    })

    runner.on('fail', () => {
        spinner.fail('Tests failed!')
    })

    runner.on('end', () => {
        spinner.stop()
    })
}
```

I have to use 'cjs' in the name of the reporter file because otherwise mocha won't load the file:

> ✖ ERROR: TypeError: Could not load reporter
> "test/mocha-ora-reporter.js":
>
> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module
> /home/foo/project/test/mocha-ora-reporter.js from
> /home/foo/project/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js not
> supported.

When I run **mocha --reporter test/mocha-ora-reporter.cjs test/integration/*.test.js** I get the following error:

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/foo/project/node_modules/ora/index.js from /home/foo/project/test/mocha-ora-reporter.cjs not supported.

I tried the following:

- add **require = require('esm')(module)** at the beginning of **mocha-ora-reporter.cjs**
- add **--require esm** in the mocha command line

none works, still having the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.